# Custom Fields Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Despite having read several things on this topic, i'm seeing myself stuck.
I have a Django Rest Framework Application. I have this model :

```
class MyModel(Model):
    name = CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    type = CharField(_('type'), max_length=50)
    users_selected = ManyToManyField(User)
```

Which i'm trying to serialize. I don't want to expose the users_selected as is seeing as it has all the users of the application whom selected this specific model, but just be able to put a boolean saying if it's selected for the current user, which i achieved by doing :

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    is_selected = SerializerMethodField('user_select')

    def user_select(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return obj.users_selected.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()

    class Meta(object):
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('users_selected',)
```

This is working fine, but now i want to do it the other way around, meaning i want my client to be able to send a request with a is_selected set to true or false and then modify my users_selected accordingly. The SerializerMethodField implies the fact that this is a read-only field.
How should I achieve this? I've tried to search by using the restore_object method, but was unable to achieve anything...

Thanks.

Comment: can't properties be serialized like methods?

Comment: I thought about it, but the thing is, I need the user in the request in order to populate this field, user I won't have on the model level with a "classic" property (then again my python knowledge may not be that deep). Plus I felt it wasn't really the right way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it feels a little strange to have MyModel point to all of the Users who selected it. This would be simpler if you subclassed the User, and gave the custom User either a Foreign key or a ManyToManyField to the MyModels selected.

If you did it this way, a single User could access his own selections, and there would be no permissions problems. The only time someone would need to access Users directly from the MyModel object would be for administrative work, at which time it would be perfectly fine to expose all of the users in the list. You could even have a separate view, something like MyModelUsersSelected, which could look like:

```
class MyModelUsersSelected(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).user_set.all()
```

This would give you all of the Users who pointed to the MyModel instance passed as a pk in the url. Since this view is separate from the MyModel and User views, permissions can be set to admin users only.